# How to reject a promise in a function of both sync and async code?

Tags: javascript, promise, try-catch, bluebird, throw

In my class I got a function that contains both sync and async code, something like:

```
export class SomeClass(){
    constructor(){
    }

    foo(a: SomeDataClass): Promise<void>{
        if(!a){
            throw new Error('a is undefined');
        }

        return doSomething(a.value).then(()=>{
            console.log('done');
        }).catch((error)=>{
            throw error;
        });
    }
}

export class SomeDataClass(){
    public value: number;
    public name: string;

    constructor(){
    }
}
```

Throwing the follow errors in the `catch` part would raise the `catch` for the user of `foo` function. but the first throw (in the `if` section) wont, in order to catch this i would have to surroun the use of `foo` within a try/catch.

How could i raise an error for the returned promise if i throw it not within a `then` section? (Without using `bluebird` and rejecting a `Resolver`)

Please let me know if something is missing.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I have found out there is a `reject` function on the `Promise` which actually does exactly what i was looking for, it raises an error for the function its used in as a `Promise` error and not like a regular `throw` to catch within a `try/catch`.

Returning this does the same a throwing an error in a `Promise.then` chains

```
foo(a: SomeDataClass): Promise<void>{
    if(!a){
        return Promise.reject('a is undefined'); //<----- Promise.reject
    }

    return doSomething(a.value).then(()=>{
        console.log('done');
    }).catch((error)=>{
        throw error;
    });
}
```

Comment: We appreciate the self answer! Please also add details about why you've picked this solution, what does it mean to `return` a rejected promise?

Comment: Done, hope that covers it well :)